# Syntax error (comma) in query expression '[delivtime_] , [delivdate_] = '9:00' , '10/17/2017''. What's wrong?

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is my SQL query:

```vb
sql = "SELECT * From CaterTrans WHERE  [delivtime_] , [delivdate_] =  '" 
    & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"

cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

If reader.Read = True Then
    Dim ans = MsgBox("This date and time is already exist", vbQuestion, "Notice!")
    If ans = vbYes Then
        TextBox1.Text = True
        DateTimePicker1.Enabled = True
        List1.Enabled = False
        Button4.Enabled = True

        TextBox1.Text = ""
        DateTimePicker1.Text = ""
```

Comment: Could you format your SQL code as code, much like you have with your VB code?

Comment: My sql code is on the top of my vb code

Comment: You misunderstand, you need to FORMAT it, like so: `sql = SELECT * FROM...`. I can't see which are single apostrophes (') and which are quote (") marks.

Comment: Never concat strings to make SQL.  Use SQL parameters always

Comment: Hhmm so what should i do?

Comment: Use SQL parameters always.

Comment: You can't separate your values in your where clause by comma like that. You need to use AND.

Comment: You should also read [ask] and take the [tour].  [This has all been explained to you recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694285/executereader-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized-i-want-to-void-date#comment80336343_46694285), so you have had *days* to research how to use DBParameters and even SQL syntax for that matter

Comment: Tuples only work in DB2

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use a [parameterized sql queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) and don't concatenate values with your query directly the way you did.

Then, your where clause is incorrect, you should add multiple filters using `AND` or `OR` not with `,` like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * From CaterTrans WHERE  [delivtime_] = @Parameter1
  AND [delivdate_] =  @Paramater2";
```

Answer (score 1):

Annabeth Moore is totally right and you should use parameters, if you didn't it would look like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * From CaterTrans WHERE  [delivtime_] = '" & 
          TextBox1.Text & "' and [delivdate_] = '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"
```

in db2 this would also work

```
sql = "SELECT * From CaterTrans WHERE  ([delivtime_], [delivdate_]) = ('"
           & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "')"
```

or from Annabeth

```
sql = "SELECT * From CaterTrans WHERE  ([delivtime_], [delivdate_]) = (@Parameter1, @Paramater2)";
```

because db2 supports tuples.